# unable to extract all users using ranger rest api user query

Tags: apache-ranger

I am able to get specific user details using following query string
/service/xusers/secure/users/305

but not able to see same user when extracted all users using
/service/xusers/users

any specific reason? I checked that there is no API call to get all users using /secure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like a bug in ranger however i was able to download entire user list using following query

/service/xusers/users?page=0&pageSize=1000&userRoleList%5B%5D=ROLE_SYS_ADMIN&userRoleList%5B%5D=ROLE_USER&userRoleList%5B%5D=ROLE_ADMIN_AUDITOR'

Answer (score 0):

please use the following API : /service/xusers/users/305 instead of /service/xusers/secure/users/305